# Displaying a UIView over the tab bar in a UITabBarController

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I'm using a `UITabBarController`. Is it possible to display a `UIView` over the tab bar of the controller?

Comment: Do you mean just a view, or another view controller's view? Do you want it to just cover the tab bar itself, not any of the content view?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `UIViewController` with `UITabBarControllerDelegate`, add a `UITabBar` to it, set the delegate. You will be able to add `UIView`s over the view controller.

[image]

Comment: I created tabbarcontroller programatically.How do i solve it?

Comment: `UITabBarController *tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init]; tabBarController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 460); [tabBarController setViewControllers: [NSArray arrayWithObjects:vc1, vc2, nil]]; tabBarController.delegate = self; [self.view addSubview:tabBarController]; [self.view addSubview:(some other ui components)];`

Answer (score -1):

If you are talking about another view controllers view then present that view controller over the tab bar controller view.For ex. lets say About is the tab inside the ta bar controller.Then when you click on the About tab it will show one view controller which is inside the tab bar controller.In that view controller in view did load you can right the below code to see the view over the tab bar controller.

```
views=[[AboutUsViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"AboutUsViewController" bundle:nil];
[self presentModalViewController:views animated:NO];
```